# Page Razor работа с MS SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Начал изучать .net Core веб разработку. Не могу дойти умом как правильно получать данные из БД двух связных таблиц в методе `OnGet`. Так же не ясно почему в методе `OnPostAsync` при вызове хранимой функции никакой ошибки в Visual Studio не выдает, просто браузер падает на 500 ошибке.

```
//Вызов хранимой функции:
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@name", name);
await context.TGoods
   .FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[FunctionFindGoods]({@name})", param)
   .ToListAsync();
```

Вообще есть источник где это написано. В плане как записывать данные, как получать правильно и т.д. Полный мануальчик так сказать.

Comment: Вы задаете вопросы по коду, что не показали. Откуда нам знать что вам править в ваших методах, если вы не привели код?

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/6.3.php